# Разный размер текста в textView

Tags: android, textview

Нужно в одном textView, на каждую строку сделать разный размер букв.
Вписал в strings.xml

```
<string name="sveiks">
        Привет!
        \nКак дела?
    </string>
```

Как это сделать?

Ниже код, не правильный. Что стоит поменять и где и как?

```
<string name="sveiks">
          <textSize="20dp">Привет!</textSize>
            \nКак дела?
        </string>
```

Comment: Вам нужен SpannableString, погуглите или поищите пример ruSO

Comment: Попробуйте менять размеры через spannable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388361/textview-with-different-textsize